# EasyMock and @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, junit, easymock

In EasyMock - you can mock an Autowired bean with the @Mock annotation
Is it possible to mock a value in Spring that is set using the @Value annotation using EasyMock without a setter method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EasyMock has nothing to do with @Autowired, it injects mocks based on the field names - see http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMockSupport.html#injectMocks-java.lang.Object- .

I guess the test still needs to provide some value to the field annotated woth @Value, so it's easy to do it programmatically in your `@Before` method.

Comment: Yes. And if you want to add a mock in a Spring context, you can use `EasyMock.mock` as a factory.